# Android: How to fade-out closed path of any shape?

Tags: android

I am choosing a path onTouch and making it closed by force. Then I'm cropping the image inside the path and redrawing it over the blurred version of original image.
But the edges look very sharp. I want the blurriness to reach its limit in an increasing rate outwards.

```
void blurIt() {
    if(path.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Selection is EMPTY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainActivity.rawBitmap.getWidth(),MainActivity.rawBitmap.getHeight(),MainActivity.rawBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(tmp);
    paintRaw = new Paint();
    paintRaw.setAntiAlias(true);

    c.drawPath(pathReal,paintRaw);
    paintRaw.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    c.drawBitmap(MainActivity.rawBitmap,0,0,paintRaw);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tmp,0,0,null); //blurred bitmap is set in canvas previously

    setImageBitmap(MainActivity.blurBitmap);
}
```

Comment: what do you need two `Canvas`es for?

Comment: the local one is for creating the cropped portion and the other one is for drawing the final bitmap

Comment: use BitmapShader and BlurMaskFilter instead

Comment: solved with BitmapShader and BlurMaskFilter, thank you very much @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by @pskink 's help.

```
void blurIt() {
    if(path.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Selection is EMPTY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainActivity.rawBitmap.getWidth(),MainActivity.rawBitmap.getHeight(),MainActivity.rawBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(tmp);
    paintRaw = new Paint();
    paintRaw.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintRaw.setDither(true);
    paintRaw.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(MainActivity.rawBitmap,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paintRaw.setShader(shader);
    paintRaw.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(20, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    c.drawPath(realPath,paintRaw);
    setImageBitmap(tmp);
}
```